# How to start afresh on stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

I created an account on StackOverflow when I had no idea of how to ask questions or what exactly needs to be asked on StackOverflow. I had just started with Python at that time. Currently I have been banned to ask questions but now I have better idea(not good yet) on which questions are for StackOverflow and which are for a forum or chat.I recently got to know about Meta, and Code Review too and here I got my first question >=0greater than or equal to 0 votes whereas on StackOverFlow I have all questions with <=0less than or equal to 0 votes. So how do I start afresh? Well, it's written to improve previous questions but those questions are too bad to be improved or some I 'm tired of improving. I can't but just delete them. What should I do?
I know deleting an account or creating multiple accounts won't help but what is the option for people who are learning to code by themselves? StackOverflow doesn't have any prerequisites but I 'm learning slowly and like I said I tried on all three sites Meta, Code Review and StackoverFlow. I got my first answer +5 on Meta , +3 on CodeReview and <=0 for all StackOverFlow. Should I take it that I 'm unfit to ask on StackOverflow ?

Comment: Rather ironically, this rambling mess of a question & the downvotes it received clearly shows you have not yet learned; the revision queue is a tale in itself.

Comment: Supportive moderators can make a user better like this-> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/226167/vishesh-mangla unlike here or SO.

Comment: My goal was to solve a problem through discussion not show any egotism. But it should be moderators job not mine to understand it since I am new here not you.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, it is a question & answer site. You learn by reading the Help pages, paying attention to what is well-received & what isn't, by forming good questions & answers, not by arguing in comments or posting wall-of-text meta questions that are almost impossible to read & make you sound like a slapped child made to stand on the naughty step.

Comment: I told already I'm waiting on stackoverflow from months to get some helpful comment. The `discussion` tag is confusion/confusing.

Answer (score 13):

I suspect the "best" approach may not make you happy.

> Currently I have been banned to ask questions but now I have better idea on which questions are for StackOverflow and which are for a forum or chat. So how do I start afresh?

So find good questions like this which you can answer and start *answering them*. Work on iterating through better answers. See what sort of questions work well. Find answers to questions you have that have been already asked by others.

Question bans do run out - so use the time to work on more broadly understanding the site, and network as more than a place to "ask questions".

And when the question ban ends, use all you have learnt to post *better* questions.

Comment: I recently answered 2 questions but this is 2020 and questions are not that easy to answer and I haven't got any feedback over those yet.

Comment: I 'm a student that too not CS background exploring technologies by randomly putting hands on stuff. That's a good answer though. I guess waiting to get a response is the only option then.

Comment: Yep, currently the ban is 6 months but I will focus on searching whatever I can do to find questions that I can answer.

Comment: @VisheshMangla You'll be allowed to ask a new question in 6 months, but the ban won't be lifted automatically at that time, if I remember correctly. It *may* be lifted if that question is received well though.

Comment: ok, but why I 'm getting -2 suddenly on this one? Is this really a duplicate?

Comment: Thia is exactly a duplicate @VisheshMangla

Comment: I wouldn't consider it though. But it's by the majority so OK.